# django, how to delete all the sessions per user

Tags: django, session-cookies, python-3.8

I have the below config in settings.py

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ]
    SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

So, we are using cache for session management, but not database.
There is already existing solution for delete from DB [Most optimized way to delete all sessions for a specific user in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656708/most-optimized-way-to-delete-all-sessions-for-a-specific-user-in-django)

but if session is cache, do we have a good way to delete user sessions by user name?

Thanks in advance.

I did not find a proper way to find the session details based on user name, from django code, I see cache key is created based on some random key, so not keyed to user name, so not sure how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Replace 'username' with the actual username or another identifier of the user.
user_to_delete_sessions_for = User.objects.get(username='username')

# Get the sessions associated with the user.
sessions = Session.objects.filter(session_key__contains=str(user_to_delete_sessions_for.id))

# Delete the sessions.
sessions.delete()
```

**and then you should Logging Out the User**

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

logout(request)
```